# Can I declare class type as array list type?

Tags: java

```
class ArrayList<A>{
  private String name;
  A(){}
  public A(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void getter(){
    System.out.println(name);
  }
}
```

I want to declare class as array list I don't know weather I can do anything like this or not, I just want to know.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Class `ArrayList` implements interface `java.util.List`. Perhaps you just want to create your own implementation for interface `List`?

Comment: I don't want to create interface.

Comment: or you can extend an `ArrayList` like `class A extends ArrayList<...>` but maybe you should write what you really want to do "declare class as" is kind of confusing

Comment: So, in ... I have to write super class or what?? @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: `...` is what ever you need to store in the list. e.g. an Integer: `... extends ArrayList<Integer>`  (but it still is somehow strange)

Comment: My final question, @CarlosHeuberger 
If I declare as you suggested and write superclass name, then class A will also be Arraylist type?

Comment: Creating a class that **implements** an interface is **not** creating an interface.

Comment: that is some basic concept of object oriented programming, a bit broad to explain here

Comment: You can create your own class `ArrayList`, even though there is already a standard class with the same name. However, it's not a good idea to name your class the same as the standard class, it will be very confusing for anyone working with your code.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger if you can explain it would be great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create but by implementing the `List<E>` interface. For example :

```
public class UserList implements List<String> { 

@Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends String> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String set(int index, String element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, String element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<String> listIterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<String> listIterator(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**You can't give class names starting with literal, keywords and primitive (pre- defined) class names.**